# Why doesn't copper react with nitrate salts?

Tags: redox

Copper reacts with nitric acid according to this equation:

$$\ce{Cu +  4 HNO3  ->  Cu(NO3)2 + 2 NO2 + 2 H2O}$$

This is a redox reaction with copper getting oxidized, and nitrogen getting reduced. If we think of the $\ce{H+}$ as a spectator ion (which I know is not exactly right, since it forms covalent bonds in water in the products), then you would have the following net ionic reaction:

$$\ce{Cu +  2 NO3-  ->  Cu^2+  +  2 NO2  + 2 O^2-}$$

I'm wondering why this reaction doesn't happen with solutions of nitrate salts (like $\ce{KNO3}$, for example). If nitrate is such a strong oxidizing agent, shouldn't the dissolved nitrate ions still be able to oxidize the copper, even without the $\ce{H+}$ around? It wouldn't be able to form water as a product, but should be able to form hydroxide ions ... something like this:

$$\ce{Cu + 2 KNO3 + 2 H2O -> 2 KOH + Cu(OH)2 + 2 NO2}$$

Is it just that forming water is necessary to make the reaction favorable, or is there something else that I'm missing about the process? (Maybe something in the mechanism where the H+ speeds it up?)

Comment: Without H+ it isn't strong anymore.

Comment: Chem+Math Expression formatting reference:
 [MathJax Basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) / [Chem+Math expressions/formulas/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) / [Upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) / [Math SE Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

Comment: O^2- is a very strong base, reacting with water as acid, forming OH-. NO2  reacts with OH-, forming NO3- and NO2-.

Comment: The simultaneous formation of $\ce{NO2}$ and hydroxides is impossible in chemistry. It will rather produce nitrites and nitrates.

Comment: Your $\ce{HNO3}$ acid acts as an acid but in your last reaction there is no acid did you try adding  some $\ce{H2SO4 }$ acid to dissolve that precipitate $\ce{Cu(OH)2}$. Which blocks the reaction. Not even pure $\ce{HNO3}$ acid will react continuously  with $\ce{Cu}$ because $\ce{Cu(NO3)2}$ is a precipitate. (I was refereeing to fuming nitric acid with no water). Normal $\ce{HNO3}$ acid has water and it dose react. Main cause is you are lacking an acidic medium.